# DateFormat.parse - parsing SHORT date works in JSE1.8 but failed in JSE 17, and vice versa

Tags: java

SHORT date below parsed ok in JSE 1.8 but failed in JSE 17

```
"12/11/2023 12:00 am"
```

SHORT date below parsed ok in JSE 17 but failed in JSE 1.8 (Notice the comma between date and time)

```
"12/11/2023, 12:00 am"
```

Is there a way to get "12/11/2023 12:00 am" to work in JSE 17 without making code change?

Below is a code example:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(java.text.DateFormat.SHORT, java.text.DateFormat.SHORT);
Date myDate = df.parse("12/11/2023 12:00 am");        
System.out.println(df.format(myDate));
```

Comment: Stop using `java.util.Date`. Move over to the newer `java.time` API

Comment: understand.  It's an existing application.   This application, along with several other applications, run in the TOMEE server. I am upgrading the TOMEE server along with JSE.  I can go search for the code and change them.  But I am afraid I might miss some.  So, want to see if there is a solution that will make those existing code still work in JSE17.

Comment: Strange, the docs are saying the same for both JDKs. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance(int,int). Do you have the same Locale in both environments.

Comment: Ahh, probably is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70572837/jdk-11-introducing-comma-in-date-format

Comment: Thank you PeterMmmm.  adding -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT did the trick